# SQL statement to insert data from source table into target table

Tags: php, mysql

The source table has 378 columns and target table has 38 columns both storing users data. Lets say my `User_ID = 10`
In the source table there are over 50 columns where my user ID can come up.

So I need a script that will search into these 66 columns and insert the number of times my user ID appears in the source table into the target table keeping in mind that 1 row will be counted as 1 irrespective of how many times my user ID appears in that row.

Currently I have following script:

```
INSERT INTO target_table (matches)
    SELECT *
    FROM match_details
    WHERE player_stats.player_id IN (col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6,col7,col8,col9,col10,col11)
```

Comment: this sentence seems contradictory for me "that will search into these 66 columns and insert number of times my user ID appears in source table into target table keeping in mind that 1 row will be counted as 1 irrespective of how many times my user ID appears in that row", can you please explain better?, and put desired output.

Comment: Your question starts with `Source table has 378 columns` and I was like o.O ?

Comment: @JuanRuizdeCastilla Lets say there are 10 columns in a table starting from ColA to ColJ. User ID '10' appears in column A, B, D, G, I & J in first row. In second row User ID '10' appears only in column A. In third row User ID '10' doesnt appear in any column. In fourth row User ID '10' appears in colum H & J. Count of User ID should be equal to 3 as it appeared in row 1, 2 & 4 irrespective of how many times it appeared in different columns for a row.

Comment: Perfect, for example when in your case what happen with the other columns in third row?, null values ? or other values ?.

Comment: @JuanRuizdeCastilla Other columns can be null or store IDs for other users

Comment: Can a given row from the source table be counted for multiple user IDs? Do you have a table of user IDs? What should go into the other columns of the target table?

Comment: @jcaron seems correctly, take a look sapphhire.

Answer (score 1):

1. Your schema needs some work. Your columns should not be columns, they should be in another table.
2. Nevertheless, if you have a table containing user IDs.

SQL:

```
INSERT INTO target_table (user_id, matches)
    SELECT u.id AS user_id, count(*)
    FROM users u
        JOIN match_details m
            ON u.id IN (d.col1, d.col2, d.col3, d.col4, d.col5...)
    GROUP BY user_id
```